# Do I need a dedicated graphic card to run some software virtualized?

Tags: virtualbox, intel-graphics, kvm-virtualization

Do i need a dedicated graphic card if i want to run softwares such as matlab,photoshop,etc on virtualbox in ubuntu.Does intel's integrated graphic card is enough or not?
i plan to have a 8 or 6gb ram with intel i7 quad core processor.please post your results if have used before.

what i need to know is there will be an performence boost using a dedicated graphic card while working with virtualized environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. VirtualBox uses your existing graphics card and does not (as far as I know) have any way of dedicating an extra graphics card to guests. In fact, VirtualBox cannot generally expose all the capabilities of your physical graphics card to guests - guests will always see a virtualbox graphics driver.

To get apps like Photoshop working well in guests, you need to install the Guest Additions software in the guest, and you need to enable 3D acceleration and allocate (usually) 64MB or 128MB of video memory in the guest settings.

Comment: thanks,so having more ram helps,but not dedicated graphic card,is that right.what about KVM,i have in some posts about it.